# Full URL in Django REST framework serializer

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a model with a FileField and a serializer for this model including the file field. In my viewset, the serializer writes a full URL (one starting with http://) for the file field without me specifying anything. But if I call manually the serializer, the url starts at /media.

Here is a little code :

```
class ArtworkView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    View that handle Artwork
    """
    queryset = Artwork.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtworkSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsArtistOrReadOnly,
    )

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

And the test that crashes because of `"http://testserver/media/file.jg" != "/media/file.jpg"`

```
def test_list(self):
        artworks = Artwork.objects.all()
        artworks_serialized = ArtworkSerializer(artworks, many=True)

        artwork = self.create_artwork()
        request = self.factory.get('/api/v1/artworks/')
        view = ArtworkView.as_view({'get': 'list'})
        resp = view(request)

        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        self.assertListEqual(resp.data, artworks_serialized.data) #crashes
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is your serialization is done out of the scope of a request.
By default, they'll be passed in the serializer context because they are required for HyperLinked data.

You should create a fake request with the RequestFactory and pass it to the serializer's context:

```
artworks_serialized = ArtworkSerializer(
    artworks, many=True,
    context={'request': request})
```

Comment: In fact there's no magic. There's a context variable that is available to the serializers and fields in order to avoid some rather ugly workaround we can see with forms